# Stripe v3 - SetupIntents and Subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to use SetupIntents to validate and save a Payment Method and then create a Subscription using it to charge the customer (inmediately and then monthly) for the required amount.

This appears to be working fine:

- The Card is validated (including SCA if needed)
- The Payment Method is created, attached to customer as default and enabled for future usage with the status SUCEEDED.
- The Subscription is created and uses the above payment method

The problem is that Stripe then generates the corresponding Invoice and Payment Intent but the latter with the status "requires_action" whenever the provided Card requires Secure Customer Authorization (SCA), even though the right payment method (enabled for future usage) is being used and the card validation has been already performed.

I thought the whole point of using SetupIntents was precisely to validate the payment method beforehand and be able to charge the customer afterwards.

Is my assumption simply wrong or this is actually possible and I might just be missing something?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: This is the subscription creation code in the backend:

```
# Set the default payment method on the customer
      Stripe::Customer.update(
        stripe_customer_id,
        invoice_settings: {
          default_payment_method: @requested_source
        }
      )

subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
       "customer" => stripe_customer_id,
       "proration_behavior" => 'create_prorations',
       "items" => [
         [
           "plan" => "#{@stripe_plan_api_id}",
         ],
       ],
       'default_tax_rates' => [
         "#{@stripe_tax_rate_id}",
       ],
       "expand" => ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"]
     });
```

Comment: Hey Eduardo, can you confirm which test card you're using? I think you'll want to test with 4000002500003155 which I believe might be the only test card that works for testing this scenario. Also, can you share the code for the Subscription create call?

Comment: @cjav_dev I'm actually using 4000002500003155 myself

Comment: Thanks for the update, and can you confirm that the Customer object  has it's invoice_settings.default_payment_method set to the payment method ID returned from the successful setup intent?

Comment: Thanks to you. Yes, I set the payment method as default before creating the subscription (edited the code above) and in the Stripe dashboard appears accordingly as default. The ID matches with the one I get from the SetupIntent.

Comment: can you pass `off_session: true` when creating the subscription?

Comment: I surely can. Can you please write that down in an answer?

Comment: I have the same situation although with a slightly different flow using Stripe Checkout. The customer is created and passed to Stripe Checkout with 'mode' => 'setup'. SCA is authorised and the session is passed back to the server. The customer default payment method is updated with the pm from the setup intent, and then the subscription is created with the same pm from the si and customer object, as well as 'off_session' => true and expanding the latest_invoice.payment_intent. The flow works with 4000002500003155 but not with 4000000000003220 or 4000000000003063. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: This solution here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74322150/6441791

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks for the question, Eduardo.

There are a couple ways to create a `Subscription` while gaining the Customers SCA authentication and permission to charge the card later. Assuming we already have a Stripe Customer object created and their ID is stored in `stripe_customer_id`. With the flow you have now there are a couple steps:

1. Create the `SetupIntent`. Note that if you create it with usage: 'off_session' and the `Customer` it'll attach the resulting PaymentMethod when confirmed.

   ```
   setup_intent = Stripe::SetupIntent.create({
     customer: stripe_customer_id,
     usage: 'off_session',
   })
   ```
2. Collect payment details and confirm the SetupIntent using its `client_secret` on the client which will attach the PaymentMethod to the customer. Note that it will attach but will not be set as the `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` by default, so you'll need to make a separate API call later to update the `Customer` (see step 3).

   ```
    stripe.confirmCardSetup(
      '{{setup_intent.client_secret}}', 
      {
        payment_method: {
          card: cardElement,
        },
      }
    ).then(function(result) {
      // Handle result.error or result.setupIntent
    });
   ```
3. Update the `Customer` and set its `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` equal to the ID of the `PaymentMethod` on the successfully confirmed SetupIntent.

   ```
   Stripe::Customer.update(
     stripe_customer_id, {
     invoice_settings: {
       default_payment_method: 'pm_xxxx', # passed to server from client. On the client this is available on the result of confirmCardSetup 
     }
   })
   ```
4. Create the `Subscription` with `off_session: true`

   ```
   subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
     customer: stripe_customer_id,
     proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
     items: [{
       plan: "#{@stripe_plan_api_id}",
     }],
     default_tax_rates: [
       "#{@stripe_tax_rate_id}",
     ],
     expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
     off_session: true,
   })
   ```

This uses what's called a "Merchant Initiated Transaction" (MIT) for the Subscription's first payment. This is technically okay if the Subscription is created later after the Customer leaves and should technically work.

If the customer is on your site/app when you create the `Subscription`, there's another flow that is a bit more correct and doesn't require using a MIT exemption for SCA. The flow is the following for a `Subscription` *without* a trial:

1. Collect card details with createPaymentMethod on the client (no `SetupIntent`)

   ```
   stripe.createPaymentMethod({
     type: 'card',
     card: cardElement,
   }).then(function(result) {
     //pass result to your server.
   })
   ```
2. Attach those card details to the `Customer`

   ```
   Stripe::PaymentMethod.attach(
     "pm_xxx", {
       customer: stripe_customer_id
     }
   )
   ```
3. Update the `Customer`'s `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

   ```
   Stripe::Customer.update(
     stripe_customer_id,
     invoice_settings: {
       default_payment_method: @requested_source
     }
   )
   ```
4. Create the `Subscription` (*without* `off_session: true`)

   ```
   subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(
     customer: data['customerId'],
     items: [
       {
         price: 'price_H1NlVtpo6ubk0m'
       }
     ],
     expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
   )
   ```
5. Use the `Subscription`'s `latest_invoice`'s `payment_intent`'s `client_secret` to collect payment details and confirm on the client.

   ```
   stripe.confirmCardPayment(
     '{{subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret}}', { ......
   ```

This second payment flow is a bit more correct from an SCA standpoint for getting authorization to charge the card. The second approach is outlined in the guide here:  https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

We also have a Stripe Sample you can use to experiment here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/master/fixed-price-subscriptions

Comment: Thanks @cjav_dev, it worked like a charm. Actually, I did implement the second flow at first, but somehow its annoying having to validate the card after you create the subscription, so I ended up trying the first one. The "off_session: true" parameter did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Does the first flow work also without setting the payment method as default? So I would just skip Step 3 and add `default_payment_method => pm_xxx` in Step 4 when creating the subscription and this should work fine, right?

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I would like to know why the first method is less 'correct' though? I am currently setting up Stripe subscription integration for my client, and the first method is the only one that will work as they offer a 7-day free trial, so SCA flow ideally needs to happen when they sign up so payment can be taken automatically after the trial ends.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm following the 2nd approach. Do you have idea on how this can be implemented for something with trial period.

@stuffedtiger1 how did you achieve this for something with trial ? I'm having trouble on getting SCA confirmation for something with trial period

Comment: Regarding the second flow "the more correct one", there is a big issue, at least with the NodeJS library: the call to subscription.create will raise an exception, so no subscription is ever created, and the text in the error is the following: Error: Payment for this subscription requires additional user action before it can be completed successfully. Payment can be completed using the PaymentIntent associated with `subscription.latest_invoice`. Additional information is available here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action which becomes a dead end...

Comment: I wonder if that is related to having a different API version, @ManuelAstudillo. Can you join us on discord.gg/stripe in the #dev-help channel if you still have tii hi s problem?

Comment: It was actually due to an older version of the API, in my case, I had to manually specify the property ```payment_behavior: "allow_incomplete"``` to avoid an exception being thrown.