# Implementing Stripe Subscription flow with free trial period with SCA

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am building a stripe integration for a client. The subscription has a 7-day free trial, following which the customer will be charged a fixed-amount every month.

I am familiar with the Stripe Subscription flow with SCA for subscriptions where the first invoice is paid immediately (and therefore SCA can be triggered on the client end for the current PaymentIntent during the customer sign-up flow), but I am unsure which is the best way to implement a solution where the first payment is not taken immediately.

The Stripe docs suggest setting up a SetupIntent instead, and then making a Merchant-Induced-Transaction (MIT), but this seems to be frowned upon and not completely compliant, not meant for dealing with free-trials? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62456011/11868365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetupIntents are exactly what you'd use for Subscriptions with trial periods. That SO question you linked to is still correct, it's exactly what Stripe Checkout does in subscription mode with free trials.