# How to create a stripe subscription with a trial period

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription flow working today that does not have a trial preriod. Howver trying to add a 7 day trial I am not sure the steps. This is what I am trying, generally following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454487/stripe-v3-setupintents-and-subscriptions/62456011#62456011)

Create the user on the backend:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=email)
```

Create a setup intent on the backend:

```
setup_intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(
            customer=cust_id,
            usage='off_session',
        )
```

Display a **payment element** on the client:

```
 this.elements = this.stripe.elements();
 this.paymentElement = this.elements.create("payment", {clientSecret: setUpObj.clientSecret});
 this.paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
```

After submit is clicked, I somehow need to confirm the payment details.
I tried this on the backend

```
si = stripe.SetupIntent.confirm(
           setup_id,
        )
```

However it throws the error `You cannot confirm this SetupIntent because it's missing a payment method`
I tried to confirm the payment method on the client

```
 const {paymentIntent, error} = await this.stripe.confirmCardSetup(
        this.setup_intent_cs,
        {
          payment_method: {
            card: this.paymentElement,
          }
        }
      );
```

But it throws the error `` Invalid value for confirmCardSetup: payment_method.card was `payment` Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods. ``

How can I confirm the payment method & move forward with creating the subscription?

Comment: This solution here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74322150/6441791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. After accepting the payment details, you need to confirm the setup without redirecting

```
const {confirmError} = await this.stripe.confirmSetup({
        element: this.paymentElement,
        confirmParams: {
          return_url: MyGlobals.THIS_URL+'/newreg',
        },
        redirect: 'if_required'
      });
```

Then create the subscription on the server

```
subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=cust_id,
            items=[{
                'price': price_id,
            }],
            payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
            expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            trial_period_days=7,
            off_session=True,
        )
```