# Stripe Payment Element with subscription and trial period

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm migrating Stripe card element to Stripe Payment Element with subscriptions following this guide https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements, but when I add the trial period to the subscription the api doesn't return the payment intent of the "expended" invoice where to get the client_secret to use with js elements.create method.
So I followed this guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element/migration?integration-path=future to use setup intent instead of payment intent, but when calling `elements.create("payment")` after instantiate the elements with this code

```js
const elements = stripe.elements({
    clientSecret: client_secret
});
```

I receive the following error from stripe:
`Uncaught IntegrationError: Missing value for elements.create('payment'): clientSecret should be a client_secret string.`
The `client_secret` variable contains a string like this `seti_1Jr36EGwrHzEL7YxdKlo86JF_secret_KW5G5nr6Dv1i9fnFhlQk9iA7yhe5tgP` taken from the setup intent.

Where I am wrong?
How can I use Stripe Payment Element with subscriptions that have trial period?

Thanks ENx

Comment: where you able to find a solution? I'm currently having the same issue

Answer (score 11):

To set up a description with a trial period, use the client_secret in the pending_setup_intent object, which needs to be expanded.

Here an example as I got it to work:

```
export const createStripeSubscription = async (customerId, priceId, trial_period) => {

  try {
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customerId,
        items: [{
          price: priceId,
        }],
        trial_period_days: trial_period,
        expand: ['pending_setup_intent'],
      });
      return {
          subscriptionId: subscription.id,
          clientSecret: subscription.pending_setup_intent.client_secret,
      }
  } catch (error) {
      return null
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it creates the client secret. But when I pass that to my elements object > stripe.elements({ appearance, clientSecret })
I get an error that "No such payment_intent: 'seti_1KNh2ZA5uxwqgSm". Can you point me in the direction how you solved this particular problem? Thanks

Comment: I hope you solved your problem but I think it's because you pass it as payment intent instead of setup intent. You may have a property setupIntentSecret (it's how it works in flutter library)

Answer (score 5):

Alex's answer works. Also, if you get the error "No such payment_intent: seti_..." after making a payment, make sure that your checkout form is configured to hit the stripe setup API and not the payment API. i.e. :

Like this:

```
const { error } = await stripe.confirmSetup({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: 'url',
  },
});
```

Instead of like this:

```
const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: 'url',
  },
});
```

Comment: `confirmSetup` and `confirmPayment` was something I missed for a while. Thanks this helped me understand that what I missed